# Traverse and Index a Text File

Tags: string, algorithm, vbscript, pseudocode

This post looks longer than it is because of all the examples. Pseudocode is ok, but I'm using vbscript. Upon overcoming many other hurdles, I am left with this final conundrum and am so far at a loss for a solution.

**-- Bottom Line --**

I am trying to come up with a **robust** algorithm for identifying an ideal "insertion point" in a text file (based on a couple criteria) to insert another block of text at that point, and shift the rest of the text down. My ultimate goal, is to insert some necessary service entries into this file at a specific location in the file for easy readability and maintainability.

For reference, I am working with the "services" file in Windows and located at the following location:

```
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\services
```

This file might look something like this:

```
 #
# <service name>  <port number>/<protocol>  [aliases...]   [#<comment>]
#
findME2     80/tcp
findME1     80/tcp
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

Ideally, this algorithm should not break for variations such as empty lines (anywhere), spaces before comments, etc.

---

So far, I have written code to read the "services" file and my template file (containing the entries to be added) into two string variables, I parse them to create a list of all combined entries of the same "type," then eliminate duplicates, sort, and finally create a new text string formatted similar to the services file.

Now I just need to insert that block of text above the first entry of some related services. For example:

**MERGED ENTRIES**

```
findME1     80/tcp
findME2     80/tcp
NEWME1      80/tcp    #New Entry
```

**INSERTION POINT**

```
# COMMENT BLOCK #
<-- INSERT HERE -->
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

**RESULT**

```
# COMMENT BLOCK #
findME1     80/tcp
findME2     80/tcp
NEWME1      80/tcp    #New Entry
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

Note the file I started with compared to the end result above. My trouble is that while iterating through each line in the file text string (using a `For Each` loop in my case), I am struggling to set the index of the location shown by my `<-- INSERT HERE -->` remark above.

---

### Questions

1. How can I identify the index at said location?
2. Is it possible to iterate through this text only once, or should I even be concerned about that? (I felt like I was seeing too many loops, but given the nature of the problem, perhaps it's not worth my time to try to optimize it, yeah?)

---

### Sample Algorithm

```vbs
Dim lines, index, indexLastComment, insertionIndex
index = 0
insertionIndex = -1
indexLastComment = -1
lines = Split(fileText, vbCrLf) 'fileText is from the "services" file
For Each line In lines
    line = Trim(line)
    If Len(line) > 0 Then 'ignore empty lines           
        'Identify ideal line to insert new "services" entries
        If (Left(line,1) = "#") Then 'If a comment
            indexLastComment = index
        ElseIf ((insertionIndex = -1) _
            And (index > indexLastComment) _
            And (Left(line,4) = "find")) Then 'If insertionIndex not set
            'This should set the insertionIndex at the location of the first line
            '  beginning with "find" so long as the index of that line is after
            '  the last comment.
            insertionIndex = index
        End If
    End If
    index = index + 1
Next
```

**Expected `insertionIndex` Samples** (0-based of course):

---

### insertionIndex = 1

```
# COMMENT BLOCK #
findME2     80/tcp
findME1     80/tcp
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

---

### insertionIndex = 2

```
# COMMENT BLOCK #

findME2     80/tcp
findME1     80/tcp
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

---

### insertionIndex = 3

```
# COMMENT BLOCK #

#
findME2     80/tcp
findME1     80/tcp
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp
```

---

### insertionIndex = 0

```
findME2     80/tcp
findME1     80/tcp
skipME1     80/tcp
skipME2     80/tcp

# COMMENT BLOCK #
```

Comment: Some hints: you could sort the entries (of the file and new), by port, protocol, and service name in that order and merge would be easy. The file don't think would be to big and would be no problem loading it full content.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're working with extremely large files, it might be more appropriate to write your program in a way that parses the input file into an array (maybe even a 2D array or an array of objects), sorts it in memory using QuickSort, or ASP.NET if you have access to that, and then overwrites the file by printing out the modified contents of your collection.

This way, you won't have to worry about low-level details like keeping track of file pointers, Other benefits: it will automatically clean up bad formatting as it goes, it'll sort any existing entries that weren't sorted correctly, and you can extend it later to do other kinds of processing.